# Variable getting expanded which is used inside another command?

Tags: shell

I am new to shell scripting .I am stuck with a very basic issue .I have a variable which I want to use with awk command to extract certain values .sample eg is below

```
sbt_value="1.0.1 analy 2.12.12"
#I want to extract each values out of this variable to three separate variable 
version=  $(echo $sbt_value |awk -F ' ' '{print $1}')
imagename=  $(echo $sbt_value |awk -F ' ' '{print $2}')
scala_version=  $(echo $sbt_value |awk -F ' ' '{print $3}')
```

I did as above but the issue I am facing is sbt_value variable get expanded on executing above script and I got error `../databricks_deploy/test.sh: line 9: 1.0.1:` command not found.

Any help on this will be appreciated

Comment: You can't put spaces after the `=`: `version=$(...)`.

Comment: https://shellcheck.net would catch this for you.

Comment: I accepted your answer .For beginner these things are must know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `read` command.

```
read version imagename scala_version <<< "$sbt_value"
```

If you are using a stricter POSIX-compliant shell that doesn't support here strings (the `<<<` syntax), you can use a here document:

```
read version imagename scala_version <<EOF
$sbt_version
EOF
```